# Why the electrons flow from higher potential to lower potential?

Tags: electricity, potential, conventions

We know that every thing moves from a higher potential to lower potential. In fact we also studied in our textbooks that a charge travels from higher potential ie. Positive side to lower potential ie. negative side. But in the case of electric current the electrons flow from negative terminal to positive terminal. I want to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a slight misconception that is that *higher potential i.e. Positive side to lower potential i.e. Negative side*. Both sides have the same electric potential just like two masses share the same gravitational potential between each other. The direction of the current is determined by which charge is less inert (the electrons). Here the gravity analogy can be used again. If you fall towards earth you are moving while the earth stays more or less put because it is much more inert. It does however have the same potential as you do. So in a circuit, the positive side is the *earth* and one electron is analogous to *you* falling.

Comment: The conventional direction for flow of charge was determined far before the microscopic physics of circuits were understood. It is arbitrary that the convention shows the direction a positive charge would take.